# Using m2e plugin in a Dynamic Web Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I have an existing Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse Indigo and the m2e plugin installed. In another version of my eclipse setup that I dont quite remember (my hdd crashed) I could just right click on the project -> Maven -> Enable Dependency Management.

This menu is gone for my Dynamic Web Project in my current eclipse version. Whats the way to go now? I tried right click on the project folder -> configure -> convert to maven project but that fails with errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

M2Eclipse has migrated to an Eclipse project from Sonatype called m2e. Therefore in you Eclipse Indigo you have installed m2e whereas your old Maven projects in the older Eclipse version were created with M2Eclipse according to your right-click description. Now under normal circomstances everything should be working flawlessly and we wouldn't have this discussion. Unfortunately with the move of the project the namespace has changed from `org.maven.ide.eclipse` to `org.eclipse.m2e.core` and old Maven projects created with M2Eclipse are not immediately recognised as Maven projects in m2e. [Here's a description](http://java.dzone.com/articles/migrating-m2eclipse-m2e) of how to migrate your projects accordingly.

Comment: Okay. But how can I make a newly created WTP project to be recognized as maven project, including dependency management, etc. ?

Comment: you want WTP support to run your maven project, presumably a webapp, in say tomcat from whithin eclipse don't you? In M2Eclipse days there was an M2Extras url where you were downloading WTP support for the M2Eclipse plugin. In the new m2e I didn't need to install any extras WTP support was there. So why don't you import a maven project in Eclipse and then do these changes described above?

Comment: Well, I just tried to create a fresh Dynamic Web Project for Tomcat in Indigo. How can I add maven support? Just adding pom.xml doesnt do it

Comment: As I said in the comment above why don't you "import an Existing Maven project" instead of creating a Dynamic Web Project? Having packaging in POM as war when you "mvn package" successfully then you can go on the server view and add a server as usual.

Comment: But I HAVE NO project existing. I want to start from scratch

Comment: Oh ok sorry I understood otherwise from what you were saying. In that case you can create a new maven project (select war packaging in the creation screen) and then it takes a WEB-INF and a web.xml to deploy it in server view in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Erik, importing an existing maven project would let m2e discover and propose you to install m2e-wtp, the Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP plugin. Since you're starting from scratch, you should install m2e-wtp yourself (see https://github.com/sonatype/m2eclipse-wtp/wiki).

Now in order to quickstart a new mavenized web project, you should go to the "New Project" menu and choose new Maven project.
At this point, either you choose to create a "simple" project, in which case you need to select the "war" packaging on the following screen, or use a maven archetype, which will quickstart a new preconfigured web project, with the flavor you want (jsf, spring ...). The m2e-wtp wiki has links to help you get started.

Note : at this point Eclipse to Maven conversion is pretty much inexistant (only creates a bare pom.xml), that's why I recommend to create a maven project first. Hopefully, this should get better in the next m2e 1.1 (June 2012)