# SpringSourceTools | Converting Maven legacy project error

Tags: maven, m2eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, m2e

I'm having a trouble converting a legacy Maven project.

I tried :-

**Right click project --> Configure --> Covert legacy Maven projects**

and it gives me an error

[image]

using m2e (1.0.2) plungin for SpringSourceTools IDE

Thanks.

Comment: What do the details say?  Please paste the stack trace.  Also, look at your Eclipse error log and post any relevant stack traces from there.  What version of STS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the project was created with the old Eclipse M2Eclipse plugin. Look at [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916552/using-m2e-plugin-in-a-dynamic-web-project/8919049#8919049) to see whether it helps you.